# Firebase Database : search by name or id issue with unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

i'm using firebase realtime database with unity c#; and i want to search by product name or id but i didn't found any solution in documentation or elsewhere.

i tried : `orderbychild("id").equalTo(MyId);`, but unity get crushed until i remove `orderbychild()` function.

I also tried to get snapshot with all data of products then filter my data using c# its working, but no one do this. All i want is to query just product i want to work with his childrens.

here is my datastructure in firebase :

```
[{
  "id": 1001,
  "price": "265$",
  "product_name": "dell",
  "type": "monitor"
}, {
  "id": 1002,
  "price": "320$",
  "product_name": "ibm",
  "type": "laptop"
}, {
  "id": 1003,
  "price": "542$",
  "product_name": "hp",
  "type": "workstation"
}]
```

Here is my code:

```
public void getProduct()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("").OrderByChild("id").EqualTo("1001").ValueChanged += S_Value_Changed;
}

private void S_Value_Changed(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{

    var players = e.Snapshot;
    Debug.Log(players.ChildrenCount);
    foreach (var player in players.Children)
    {
        if (player.Child("code").GetValue(true).ToString() == "1001")
            Debug.Log(player.Child("product_name").GetValue(true).ToString());
    }
}
```

Note: i don't want to make id as parent of products because i want to search also using product name.

Comment: You've included a picture of the schematic JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: here is my json
[
  {
    "id": 1001,
    "price": "265$",
    "product_name": "dell",
    "type": "monitor"
  },
  {
    "id": 1002,
    "price": "320$",
    "product_name": "ibm",
    "type": "laptop"
  },
  {
    "id": 1003,
    "price": "542$",
    "product_name": "hp",
    "type": "workstation"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operations in Firebase as type-sensitive. Your code checks for `EqualTo("1001")`, but the JSON has a value `1001` as a number. The two are not the same, so are not returned by the query.

To compare the numeric value:

```
OrderByChild("id").EqualTo(1001)
```

Comment: the problem isn't in type or value, the real problem become when i add OrderByChild() function to my code then unity show small window "hold on" for ever as you can see in picture bellow
https://freeimage.host/i/HKPvOP9

Comment: I don't know what that means, but what I pointed out in my answer is definitely a reason why the `getProduct` function you shared won't work against the data you shared.

Comment: what i mean is when i add OrderByChild() function to the code , unity stop working and don't want to play so i have to quit from task manager and open unity 3d again and remove the orderby function to get my code work again

Comment: Did you add an index for the `id` property to your rules? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data